# Javascript: read a file without user select it

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

Is possible to read a file from the filesystem into a client side JavaScript environment?

I would read a file only by code, so the user haven't to browse the filesystem and select the file.

I have already seen [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Is it within the browser or is it a custom mobile app?

Comment: @kolossus please don't edit for one word changes only! (Bhushan Kawadkar too)

Comment: No, browser security prevents reading arbitrary files. The user will need to select the file with a file input for you to be able to read it.

Comment: I hope not.  Would you want some unknown process reading and writing files without your knowledge?

Comment: Fortunately, it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

It will breach browser security and hence it is not possible. `Imagine websites stealing your files!!!`

You can achieve this if you are developing mobile application. AFAIK, It is not possible in a pure html / js way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the client file system directly from javascript for security.
You can only do it with a plugin